# Self-winding wristwatches on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, time

Can self-winding wristwatches be used on Shabbos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Shemiras Shabbos K'hilchoso, 28:28:

> שעון אוטומאטי, דהיינו שעון שמכונן את עצמו על–ידי תנועת היד, מותר לענוד אותו בשעה שהוא פועל

Which means:

> It is permitted to wear an automatic watch, which is a watch that winds itself through the movement of the hand, as long as it is still ticking.

Comment: I think he was referring to a mechanical automatic watch. Not sure what he would say about the watches that charge up a battery through hand motions.

Comment: What I saw is he does he differentiates between the digital display watches in which you cause writing those he says are assur