# Personal Air Purifiers and Shabbath

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology

What implications might there be for a [personal air purifier](http://mashable.com/2013/07/12/hand-tree-purifier/) on Shabbath?  Would it be the same as wearing a watch, even a [self-winding watch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5610/5), which according to most is Mutar on Shabbath?  Or is it a problem because its primary function is to do Melachah for you wherever you go?