# Fitness Tracker On Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, sport-athletics

First I want to assure everyone that I asked this question to a proper halakhic authority and will proceed with my actions based on his answer. I am asking it here as well because I think it is an interesting question.

Can one wear a fitness tracker on shabbat if it is worn as a watch? The device would always show the time, but it would be collecting data in the background. Then after shabbat use the data that the device collected for whatever abstract personal interest a person might have with the data.

The [Garmin Vivofit](http://sites.garmin.com/vivo/) is the specific device I am speaking about.

Comment: Are you asking if it can be worn outside the home in a public domain? Is this device placed on the wrist before the onset of Shabbos?

Comment: This depends a lot on on why you hold that electricity on Shabbos is forbidden. Can you explain your position? There may also be an issue of kosaiv, if you hold that the av melocho of kosaiv is making a record and not making two meaningful permanent symbols.

Comment: @user4751 I meant in terms of electricity, but I guess that is an important aspect of the question as well. Assume it starts on the wrist and remains on the wrist throughout shabbat.

Comment: @Tatpurusha unfortunately I am not familiar with the specifics of either of those issues, so I have not formulated a position on them.

Comment: @Jordan In general, most poskim agree that all electronic devices are prohibited on Shabbos at least on the level of minhag. It surely would be better to refrain from using a pedometer on Shabbat, but I couldn't tell you if it were actually forbidden without a lot more information. Googling "shabbat pedometer" brought up several blog entries where observant exercise enthusiasts mention that they turn off theirs for the holy day.

Comment: @Tatpurusha - Not true, Rav Moshe and Tzitz Eliezer both allowed a hearing aid on Shabbat.

Comment: @Master_Yoda In the case of a minhag you can push them aside in cases like a hearing aid AFAIK.

Comment: @Tatpurusha - Just making the point that not all electronic devices are prohibited. This particular device being a passive device which doesn't have the problems of noise or heat, and is not causing any direct benefit on shabbat, and might have health ramifications too, might be different. This question requires more careful consideration than a simple dismissal.

Comment: @Master_Yoda I sure hope my point that it is better to not use such a device on Shabbos, but I don't actually know if it's *forbidden* per se came across...

Comment: @Tatpurusha - If it is permitted and could have a positive health benefit, why is it better not to use it?

Comment: @Master_Yoda I think it's fair to say that exercise is a concern of the week. The rabbis have forbidden most forms of strenuous exercise on the Sabbath for their own sakes, including running. A device that's only used for the sake of exercise is plainly permissible on the Sabbath?

Comment: @Tatpurusha - Exercising on Shabbat is problematic. I understood that this device also served to provide regular health tracking information (heart rate, sleep monitoring, etc) aside from the exercise tracking information. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Master_Yoda The device appears to me to be a computerized pedometer/watch with an optional heart-rate attachment. https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/prod143405.html

Comment: @Tatpurusha - Interesting... strenuous exercise is problematic on shabbat, but I don't know that collecting information on your movements means would be included in this prohibition. Especially when they're only being analyzed after shabbat. When I have some time, I'll try to look into this properly.

Comment: @Master_Yoda According to Dovid Ribiat's sefer "39 Melocho," making records of any kind is a toldos of kosaiv.

Comment: @Tatpurusha Does that include making them passively as one does in this case? With no melechet machshevet either.

Comment: @Master_Yoda Yes, he specifically mentions that one should avoid walking in front of a security camera for this reason, although he stops short of actually declaring such to be assur since sometimes it's unavoidable.

Comment: Interesting. Rav ovadiah is matir in that situation. See yabia omer 9:35.

Comment: see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98638/11501) for the view of R Rozen from Tzomet

Comment: Please note that many smartwatches only show the time when you press a button or move your wrist, although the latter function can be deactivated.

Comment: I think some of the comments here should be made into answers, with the sources shown

Answer (score 2):

I've asked R. Ari Hart (Hebrew Institude of Riverdale) for guidance in this matter, so I will share here what he told me in the hopes it helps you answer your question.

Devices like these measure the steps you take, and measuring is prohibited on Shabbos. However, since you're not measuring, you let the computer do it, it may be OK. It would be better if you had no way of knowing how many steps you'd taken on Shabbos until Shabbos was over - maybe.

If your pedometer has a watch function, it gives you a leniency, however - you can wear your pedometer as a watch, and the step tracking is incidental. I have a FitBit Flex (no watch function) and am still unsure whether wearing it is kosher on Shabbos. (It probably isn't, but it could be if the developer wrote a Shabbos Mode into the software.)

I doubt that wearing a pedometer as a watch or bracelet would count as carrying - at least, it doesn't for electric watches.

The last thing to consider is whether wearing your pedometer is in the spirit of Shabbos. If you're tempted to check it or fiddle with it, or if it distracts you from Shabbos, then R. Ari advised me to leave it at home, even if there wasn't a definite halakic reason not to wear it.

This consideration is my own: does your pedometer set off any lights or vibrations to tell you you met your goal? Progress lights? Could you set these lights off accidentally e.g. by tapping the device? These would probably violate prohibitions against measuring things and switching lights on/off.

Answer (score -4):

In Kistur Shulchan Aruch there is a paragraph about wearing watches on Shabat. As far as I remember, it is written that it's surely allowed for women to wear watches on Shabat because it's not only a practical object but also a beauty item. 
For men, nowadays it is allowed based on the fact that it is an usual clothing item.

Although in a footnote, it is stated: Blessed be he who is strict in this manner.

The above said, is about watches. If this fitness tracker you talk about has internet acces or "collects data" it falls in the category of muctse. So its forbidden for another reason. Further, it is not an usual clothing item, mainly in those places we go at Shabbos such as the Synagoge and festive meals.

Ps: If you wear digital watches, remember you cant press any of its buttons during Shabbos!
Pss: Ask your rabbi for his answer. Good luck there! Good Shabbos!

Comment: If it has internet access it is muktza?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Tsivia, where we highly value sourced answers. Can you [edit] in any source for your substantive claims, please, both into this and into your other answers? In particular, for the claim that a fitness tracker, as opposed to a watch, is _muktze_ and doesn't count as a usual clothing item.

Comment: The Kitzur [84:2](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0083_L2) is talking about pocket watches.