# Different Smart/Sport Watches on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, technology, modern-times

I looked at some of the other smartwatch threads, and being that they were older, they don't cover the following two cases:

- Hybrid Smartwatches
- Sports watches

First the assumptions / definitions

- I assume that you are in agreement that a regular, battery powered
  watch, with an always on screen is okay to wear on shabbat
- For this discussion - a "Hybrid Smartwatch" is a regular date/time watch, but has a sensor within it that tracks your steps - this sensor doesn't have a
  display, and the information is only available to you, if you sync
  your phone with the watch.
- A sports watch (for purposes of this discussion) is a watch that has the following features: a) The screen is always on, b) it may have GPS and/or Heart rate measurement - but this only operates when you press a button to go into 'workout' mode, and c)It tracks steps, but doesn't display them on your screen

So now my questions:

- Can either of these watches be used on Shabbat? What modifications would need to be made? (or is the fact that they're tracking steps make them prohibited off the cuff)?
- In the case of the Hybrid Smartwatch, would it make a difference if you never sync your phone with it?

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8725/wearing-watches-on-shabbat

Comment: @ezra that was in 2011!

Comment: @AlBerko Your point is...?

Comment: High key related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37772/11501

Comment: "Hybrid" changes nothing in watches as the analog part is known to be OK.

Comment: I would assume that there is at the very least a potential problem of what happens if the watch accidentally gets knocked into the wrong mode on Shabbos and you have the temptation to switch it back, or even the temptation to switch it into that mode in the first place.  It would be easy to do so without thinking about it, which I think some people say is a possible problem with classical digital watches.  I actually had a phase of using cheap digital watches with the buttons glued in place on Shabbos to avoid that (unfortunately the glue didn't hold - I keep meaning to try epoxy)

Answer (score 1):

I have now looked at this in detail, the overwhelming consensus of decisors is that it is **not permitted to wear a smartwatch on Shabbat**. I would note that since the question was written most of today's smartwatches combine the functions you describe.

R Ike Sultan (the founder of Halachipedia) surveys the various reasons given ([here](https://thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/wearing-a-smartwatch-on-shabbat/))

- **the watch's wearer intends to use the data collected by the watch on Shabbat, and benefits from it**, as such it is *pesik reisha de niha leih* which is forbidden - unlike a video camera in front of which many permit walking
- **the results (data collected by the watch) are observable and intentional** - unlike a digital fridge which many permit opening
- by wearing the watch one is causing it to monitor one’s health and **record data in a computer chip** which is categorized under the *melakhah* of writing, erasing, or constructing.

See [bottom of D and G](https://thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/wearing-a-smartwatch-on-shabbat/) for exceptions in which this might be permitted, maybe for someone who doesn't use the smart functions of the watch, although to me it defeats the purpose of wearing one.

Poskim ruling this way include R Hershel Schachter and Rav Mordechai Willig ([article](https://thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/wearing-a-smartwatch-on-shabbat/) cited above), R Yirmiyohu Kaganoff ([here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/4133)), R Rashi Simon ([here](https://kesher.org.uk/knowledge-base/shabbat-and-digital-technology/)), R Pinchas Waldman ([here](https://aish.com/pedometer-fitbit-on-shabbat/)). R Binyamin Tabady also ruled to forbid (personal communication).

On the lenient side, R Yisrael Rosen ([here](https://www.zomet.org.il/?CategoryID=398&ArticleID=1050)) argues it is technically permitted but highly discouraged in practice since it isn’t in the spirit of Shabbat, and R Yosef Zvi Rimon is quoted as permitting a fitbit.

This being said, everyone should [consult their rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: Since none of the above relates to the original answer (on smart watches), I will delete my comments and encourage you to do the same

Answer (score -1):

1. Causing changes in electricity is generally prohibited.
2. So, causing all kinds of electrical activities in the watch purposefully and actively, like waving a hand for changing steps count or pressing buttons or changing screens is prohibited. So any use of watch that intentionally results in minor changes in watch's circuits is bad :(.
3. Some accept that unintentional and unwanted changes (called לא ניחא ליה) are allowed. For example, taking a solar-powered watch from inside a building to outside is not a problem as long as one is not interested in charging it. Or wearing a step-counting watch for one that's not aware of that function is also allowed under this approach.
4. Also, any activity that's automatic and autonomic and not user triggered, such as pulse sampling every 5 mins is not a problem just like a regular quartz watch moving its hands.

Another example to clarify the difference - use of GPS tracking (only for the purpose of differentiating the two):

- if one activates GPS in advance and the watch samples GPS coordinates every second as long as it is autonomous it would not be a problem as the watch works on its own,
- but if the user enters a building and GPS freaks out - that's is user-generated and is prohibited.

Comment: Interesting but without sources, and doesn't answer the key question. Can one wear a watch that captures data the user is interested in (e.g., steps) without intervention, knowing the data will be used after Shabbat. I asked rabbanim and the answer is no but it would be nice to cover it and source it where you can. Also your point 4 might be wrong (in the case where you want and use the data after Shabbat) unless you can source it.

Comment: @mbloch You misunderstanding stems from the origin of the data, not the data itself, as I mentioned (maybe not so clear). If the data comes from an activity that's user-generated **actively**, like waving a hand to activate the motion sensor it is prohibited, but if it is not triggered by the user, even if it monitors him, it is allowed (like periodic HR sampling). Is that more clear now?

Comment: Your opinion is clearer but I am afraid it is wrong. Do you have any sources that passively triggering electric signals to achieve a desirable outcome is permitted ?

Comment: @mbloch what do you mean by passively? I only spoke of either actively or autonomously. What example of mine you're referring to.

Comment: I guess your autonomous is my passive. Passively for me means wearing a watch that captures data without interacting with it. Most watches these days count heartbeats and steps without interactions but use the information after Shabbat

Comment: @mbloch HR and steps are very different that's exactly what i'm trying to differentiate. Waving your hand is voluntary and that CAUSES changes in counting and that's forbidden but if something external is measuring your vital data there's nothing in you that causes it. It's like somebody taking a digital photo of you.

Comment: Well if a Jew takes a picture of you on shabbat, you are forbidden to enjoy it afterwards...

Comment: @mbloch  from Motzaey Shabbos and on it's permitted for everyone. But the watch is not מעשה שבת  by a Jew, so it is allowed imediately.

Comment: I have been told that a watch that recharges a battery by hand movements or a what that recharges the bettery by being moved into sunlight would be forbidden to be worn on shabbos. I have also been told that if the battery would last for more than the full extent of shabbos without being recharged, it might be permitted. However, I do not have sources, so I cannot give an answer.

Comment: @sabbahillel Exactly what I'm saying - לא ניחא ליה - usually, the charge lasts for months (my solar Casio lasts about 6 months without any light source), that's why it would be permitted. But beware - we're not talking Halachah here, as different Rabbis have different bars for Shabbos observation (and understanding of the technology :)