# Is it permissible to carry around an air tag or tile tracker on shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, contemporary-halacha, modern-times

Assuming you were within an eruv would you be able to carry around a tracker? You do not turn the device on and off but it can communicate with other tracking devices as you walk.

Comment: Do you mean carry it around by itself or eg. on a bunch of keys that you are carrying to get into your house?  I suspect there may be a difference

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing this interesting question. Check out the ? at the top and read the site tour and help center if you haven't already, and we look forward to learning with you

Comment: I mean to carry it on a set of keys which would let me into my apartment. The tracker would be to track the keys if they every went missing

Comment: See [this article](https://asktherav.com/2874-if-my-house-keys-are-in-my-coat-pocket-with-a-tile-key-finder-attached-to-it-does-it-make-my-coat-muktza-for-shabbos/) which rules the tracker is *muktzeh* with some permitting to carry on a keychain and others not

Answer (score 1):

I believe since everything the airtag/tile does is completely not discernible to the naked eye i.e. you can not see it doing anything, there is no problem on Shabbos as a result of the electronic elements. Similar to why there is no issue opening a refrigerator even though there are microprocessors inside measuring temperatures and time the door is open etc.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? To me that does not appear to be a sufficient reason. For instance, one cannot carry a digital watch that measures your heart rate if you will use this data later on. It would be benefitting from *maase Shabbat*.

Comment: I suppose you would only be benefitting from the data if you happened to lose the keys on shabbat. And even then I would not track it until after shabbat, would this change the scenario in your opinion?

Comment: @mbloch Do you have a source for this? I am saying it is NOT masseh Shabbat if what the device is doing is undetectable/visible to the naked eye. My source - a shiur I heard on the usage of water meters on Shabbos ....

Comment: @Draizy-LeviPine I have written up the various sources [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/138499/11501) and they contradict both your answer and comment, which is why I was asking for your source

Comment: @JoshZwiebel the case of an AirTag is possibly different from a smart watch because in most cases you would never use the data - you would need to ask a Rav whether it makes it permitted (possibly using the reasons mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/138499/11501))